# Displaying Username - Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have looked ALL over the internet and found nothing, Please help me. Im trying to figure out how I can display a username from parse in my table view (`detailTextLabel`). When I do the code below  my app only shows the `PFUser Id` not the username. It will display: `<PFUser:H2AhEbYGal:(null)> {` but I'm trying to display the username of that post.

Heres me saving the object:

```
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
    quoteNew[@"author"] = user;
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
```

Here is me trying to retrieve the user in a `PFQuery`:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects'
            [query includeKey:@"author"];
           // PFObject *testObject = [query findObjects];
           // PFUser *testUser = [testObject objectForKey:@"author"];
           // NSLog(@"username: %@",testUser.username);

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Here is me trying to display it:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[object objectForKey:@"author"],[dateFormat stringFromDate:updated]];
```

You can just worry about `[object objectForKey:@"author"]` in that `cell.detailTextLabel.text` code.

Comment: Could you help me!? Please! @rmaddy

Comment: repleace this quoteNew[@"author"] = user; with quoteNew[@"author"] = user.username;

Comment: Now when I do that the whole post won't display in the tableview @pawan

Comment: Do I have to use `_User` instead of `author`? @pawan

Comment: [object objectForKey:@"author"] will return you a PFUser object, you need to type cast it as PFUser . then you can user username property from it. here is [reference](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects'
        [query includeKey:@"author"];
       // PFObject *testObject = [query findObjects];
       // PFUser *testUser = [testObject objectForKey:@"author"];
       // NSLog(@"username: %@",testUser.username);

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Should be:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];

// BEFORE WE QUERY
[query includeKey:@"author"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // Get your objects here

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

And this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[object objectForKey:@"author"],[dateFormat stringFromDate:updated]];
```

Should be:

```
PFUser *userToDisplay = object[@"author"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",userToDisplay.username,[dateFormat stringFromDate:updated]];
```

Because, as it stands, problem 1 is you're saying to include the author AFTER you have already queried parse.  Problem 2 is that you're trying to display the whole user, you need to get the user, and then print the username value.